# UIAlertView outside app

Tags: objective-c, uialertview

On iOS which is the class name used to show UIAlertView outside the application, like the notification system does?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use local notifications, or setup apple's Remote Push notification service.

[Local Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html)

[Push Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/WhatAreRemoteNotif/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW1)